# Merge two lists python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, functional-programming

```
a = [0, 2, 4]
b = list(map(lambda x: x+1, a))
```

merged list c = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

`c =  [a[0], b[0], a[1], b[1] ... ]`

Can I achieve the result with functional programming ?
Instead of just looping ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, there are many ways. Here is a straightforward list-comprehension:

```
>>> a = [0, 2, 4]
>>> b = [1, 3, 5]
>>> [p for pair in zip(a,b) for p in pair]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

Or if you would prefer to use `itertools`

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(a,b)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a functional way:

```
from operator import add
reduce(add,zip(a,b),[])
```

Comment: `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list`

Comment: use `import operator; operator.add` instead of the dunder method.